# React native -Firebase "Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.timestamp'."

Tags: firebase, react-native

Hi I'm trying to make chat app with firebase. I'm following this tutorial

[Build a React Native Chat App with Firebase in 20 MINUTES!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR1vP-W1emI&ab_channel=DesignIntoCode)

This is my Fire.js. It's exactly same with the video but its not working in my pc

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
class Fire{
constructor(){
    this.init()
    this.checkAuth()

}
init=()=>{
    if(!firebase.apps.length){
        firebase.initializeApp
        ({
            apiKey: "AIzaSyBK4qmCasdasfQAX9JSiaEeWh0-33f56IlrU",
            authDomain: "chatko.rfirebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://chatkor.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "chatkor",
            storageBucket: "chatkor.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "452131431250",
            appId: "1:4576325263250:web:6basd1698c9c68db75d54b",
            measurementId: "G-8SJ1eeqdV1H"
        })
    }
};
checkAuth=() =>{
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        if(!user){
            firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
        }
    });
};

send=messages=>{
    messages.forEach(item=>{
        const message={
            text:item.text,
            timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.timestamp,
            user: item.user
        };
        this.db.push(message);
    });
};
parse=message=>{
    const {user,text,timestamp}= message.val();
    const {key:_id} =message;
    const createdAt=new Date(timestamp);

    return{
        _id,
        createdAt,
        text,
        user
    };
};
get=callback=>{
    this.db.on('child_added',snapshot=>callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
};

off(){
    this.db.off();
};
  get  db(){
    return firebase.database().ref('messages');
}

    get uid(){
    return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
}
}
 export default new Fire();
```

It gives this error
Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.timestamp'

Comment: you are not putting get keyword before db and uid so that is why

Comment: yeah it fixed this area but now it gives Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.timestamp'